# UPDATING A MYSQL TABLE COLUMN BASED ON A STATUS IN ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I would like to update the status of one column in one table based on the status of a column in another table...
Table 1 is users, table 2 is Activation

In table one, I have a column called account_active and in table two I have a column called status.

I want to attain the following.
to update column called is_account_active to 2 in users table where status is 2 in table 2 this is the first query
the second, I want the user table column account_active to be set to 1 if the status in activation table is not 2

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your own sql like syntax, Can you please describe your problem in plain English text.

Comment: Done, please unto it

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes i finally got the answer to question 1. now remaining the second query

UPDATE users JOIN user_account_actives ON users.id = user_account_actives.user_id SET users.is_acc_activate = user_account_actives.status WHERE user_account_actives.status = 2

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM `user_account_actives` WHERE `user_account_actives`.`status` = !2;

if the status is not 2 it will delete. now I am sorted. Happy codding